# how to to make a car park shows different colors for each dots using matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I convert my car park image to binary image and clear the unwanted white dots/region to get this image:

[image]

This is my codes:

```
sceneImage = imread('nocars10green.jpg');
figure;
imshow(sceneImage);
hsvscene = rgb2hsv (sceneImage);
figure;
imshow (hsvscene);
grayscene = rgb2gray (hsvscene);
figure;
imshow (grayscene);
bwScene = im2bw (grayscene);
figure;
imshow (bwScene);
str = strel('disk',4)
bw = imerode(bwScene,str)
figure;
imshow (bw);
```

How do I convert the binary image after erode so that I can show different colors for different dots?

I read in this journal.

Al-Kharusi, Hilal, and Ibrahim Al-Bahadly. "Intelligent parking management system based on image processing." World Journal of Engineering and Technology 2014 (2014).

it is mentioned:

if `(newmatrix(y,x) > 0)` % an object is there, if `(e(newmatrix(y,x)) = 0)` this object has not been seen
`(newmatrix(y,x)) = x;` make the value and index 3 equal to the current `X` coordinate.

and this is their output image:

[image]

But I don't understand how it works. Can anyone explain to me how it work and how to write the commands to convert my binary image to get the same as their output image in order to get different colors of each dots?

or if there is any other way to convert it?

Comment: This is my original image with 10 green dots.
[![nocars10green.jpg](https://s27.postimg.org/5hkacdhpv/nocars10green.jpg)](https://postimg.org/image/lske8ou7j/)

Comment: @JoselynJok don't delete all your code, obviously. Just don't use a HTML snippet when you're posting MATLAB code. I fixed it for you, please take care of that next time. Simply indent code with four spaces to make it show as readable code.

Comment: @Adriaan Sorry, I am new to SO and thank you for the info, I will take note of it.

Comment: Also when you're using someone else' idea, always properly reference it. *Which journal, which paper, which authors, what year?*

Comment: @SardarUsama noted. I insert the citation of the journal.

Answer (score 0):

The term you have to search the web for is connected component labeling or just labeling.

Given the provided image with 10 white dots on black background you can do the following:

Find the blobs:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling

https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html

Then color them. For example by using label2rgb:

> You can display the output matrix as a pseudocolor indexed image. Each
>   object appears in a different color, so the objects are easier to
>   distinguish than in the original image. For more information, see
>   [label2rgb](https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/label2rgb.html).